# Ajax - SQL - Return rows for everything

Tags: php, sql, ajax

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/json');

    if(!isset($_POST['username']))
        exit;
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=ASDFSDF;dbname=QWEQWESAD','SDFSDF','ASAsaD_',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mybb_users WHERE username =\''.$_POST['username'].'\'');
    $query->execute();

    echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->rowCount() > 0));
    exit;
?>
```

It returns that rows exist for all the usernames that I send though they actually do not exist.

EDIT1: http://pastebin.com/DWb7uZV1
With binding doesn't work

Comment: check if $_POST['username'] is passed to PHP and try use bindValue

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DWb7uZV1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual on the rowCount method is quite clear. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() **does not** return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

So what you want to do is use a count query.

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/json');

    if(!isset($_POST['username']))
        exit;

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=ASDFSDF;dbname=QWEQWESAD','SDFSDF','ASAsaD_',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM mybb_users WHERE username = ?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    //echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->fetchColumn() > 0));
    echo json_encode($query->fetchColumn() == 0);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: You have syntax error edit and correct this before someone down vote.

Comment: I think we are supposed to use ' before providing any string to the query?Without it will cause a syntax error?

Comment: BindParam will do this for you automatically if you indicate the paramater is a string. It will also escape the variable to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: It still doesn't work!Perhaps this code have a problem?<input name="username" data-idealforms-ajax="ajax.php" type="text">

Comment: Is the problem the same? Or different?

Comment: I just tested the code I submitted and it works. Are you actually seeing json returned? Or you get nothing.

Comment: http://xacnr.com/default/secure/register.php?reflink=/default/index.php - thats the webpage - it doesn't work

Comment: rules: {
         'username': 'required username ajax',
         'email': 'required email',
         'password': 'required pass',
         'confirmpass': 'required equalto:password',
         'date': 'required date',
         'website': 'url',
         },
 
       errors: {
         'username': {
           ajaxError: 'Username not available'
         }
    },

Comment: Edited to work with your library. It says right here, return TRUE if passed validated and FALSE if failed. https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms#extension-ajax

Comment: It working -.- now I have a problem with my form code

Comment: Good to know. I think that means your original questions has been answered. If you run into new problems I suggest you open a new question. Please up-vote